# What's the most efficient way to convert several win forms in VB2008 to a tabbed form?

Tags: winforms

I have developed an application inside ESRI ArcMAP that uses several forms that are raised by buttons on a toolbar. I'd like to convert these forms to a set of tabs on a single form. Is there a way to bind the forms to individual tabs or do I have to just recreate the form as controls on each tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreate each form as a UserControl.  You should be able to mostly just copy and paste the controls and code.  Once you get to that point you can easily stick each UserControl on its own tab.